# Add Flutter Iterable map result into List Array

Tags: flutter, dart

We have this iterable:

```
  Iterable<void> intoarray = listaMap.interests!.map((f) => f['id']);
  print(intoarray); <--- result: flutter: (1, 3, 4)
```

And I want add the result into this array:

```
  List<int?> arrayValues = [];
  arrayValues.add(intoarray result elements)
```

Should I parse to int for this? How can I put this results int Array? One by One or everything at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a posible solution for your question.

```
void main(){
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> listaMap = [
    {
      "id":1,
    },
    {
      "id":2,
    },
    {
      "id":3,
    }
  ];
  // Your code
  //Iterable<void> intoArray = listaMap.map((f) => f['id']);
  //print(intoArray);
  
  //Solution
//   // if id is always int
//   List<int> arrayValues = listaMap.map((f) => f['id'] as int).toList();
//   // if id is nullable
//   List<int?> arrayValues = listaMap.map((f) => f['id'] as int?).toList();
  
  // if id is String
//   List<int?> arrayValues = listaMap.map((f) => int.tryParse(f['id'])).toList();
//   print(arrayValues);
  
  // if id is dynamic
  List<int?> arrayValues = listaMap.map((f) {
    final id = f['id'];
    if (id is int){
      return id;
    }else if (id is String){
      return int.tryParse(id);
    }
    return null;
  }).toList();
  print(arrayValues);
}
```